# How to Completely remove mono?

Tags: 12.04, uninstall, mono

I've been trying to remove mono completely from my Ubuntu 12.04 installation.

I have seen a few other posts with:

```
sudo apt-get purge mono-runtime  
sudo apt-get purge mono-complete  
sudo apt-get purge libmono* libgdiplus cli-common libglitz-glx1 libglitz1
```

I've run all those and done `sudo apt-get update` but when I type `mono -V` it's still there.

I'm trying to remove it completely to re install again with the latest beta build `Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8 (tarball Wed Oct  2 16:46:11 CEST 2013)` Is the version I have currently but NEED the latest beta build.

Comment: Can you run `whereis mono` and tell me the output please?

Comment: `mono: /usr/lib/mono /usr/local/bin/mono /usr/local/etc/mono /usr/local/lib/mono` @Grammargeek

Comment: How about `dpkg --list | grep mono`?

Comment: `ii  fonts-tlwg-mono                        1:0.4.17-1ubuntu1                     Thai TlwgMono font
ii  monodoc-manual                         4.0.2.5-0xamarin1                     compiled XML documentation from the Mono project
ii  ubuntu-mono                            0.0.40                                Ubuntu Mono Icon theme`
@Grammargeek

Comment: Those naughty naughty mono contributers. Try `sudo rm -rf usr/lib/mono /usr/local/bin/mono /usr/local/etc/mono /usr/local/lib/mono` (BACK IT UP FIRST!)

Comment: `The program 'mono' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
apt-get install mono-runtime` @Grammargeek Thanks! Now to hopefully get the beta build to install properly.

Comment: Youre welcome ill make my answer now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok simply run `sudo rm -rf usr/lib/mono /usr/local/bin/mono /usr/local/etc/mono /usr/local/lib/mono` in terminal.

Comment: I know this answer is old, but I'd like to point out that after issuing above commands, `/etc/ca-certificates/update.d/mono-keystore` is running dry, because it does not find the mono `cert-sync` binary. Manually messing around with `rm` is rarely a good idea... I would recommend `apt list --installed '*mono*'` first and then remove the unwanted packages (not ALL the listed, because that would remove `ubuntu-mono` icon theme) that are listed there. If that doesn't catch everything, move on with Lino Barreca's answer below.

Comment: another way to list mono* packages `apt list --installed | grep ^mono`

Answer (score 42):

```
sudo apt remove --purge --auto-remove mono-runtime
```

This will then completely remove mono from your system to correct the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did on my 16.04
Before someone starts raging and telling me there was a better, faster and more concise way to do that: Yes, I know. I took the "long way" to analyze the results of each step and triple check what I was doing.

1. be su:
   `sudo -i`
2. list all the packages from the mono repository (into file pkg1):
   `grep ^Package: /var/lib/apt/lists/download.mono-project.com*_Packages > pkg1`
3. extract just the package names (into file pkg2):
   `sed -e 's/^.*Package: //' pkg1 > pkg2`
4. (optional but I wanted to do that anyway) remove duplicate package names from different architectures and put definitive list of packages to search for and remove in pkg3:
   `awk '!seen[$0]++' pkg2 > pkg3`
5. (optional, for check) count the lines in the files (one line = one package) to see what happened:
   `wc -l pkg1` and `wc -l pkg2` and `wc -l pkg3`
6. remove packages listed in pkg3:
   `apt purge $(cat pkg3)`
7. cleanup and exit su:
   `rm pkg1 pkg2 pkg3` and `logout`